# Un-check Checkbox when selecting another

Tags: java, android, android-checkbox

I know this sounds simple but hear me out. I have 2 checkboxes, when one of them are selected I want to un-check the other one.

I have tried the following:

```
CheckBox chk1, chk2;

if (chk1.isChecked()) {
    chk2.setChecked(false);
}

if (chk2.isChecked()) {
    chk1.setChecked(false);
}
```

I have also tried:

```
chk1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
        chk2.setChecked(false);
    }
});

chk2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
        chk1.setChecked(false);
    }
});
```

I know that I should use a toggle button instead, but the checkbox works with the design, so I'm looking for a way to make this work.

Any ideas?

Comment: How about handling the click event instead of checkedChange event?

Comment: I can quickly try that, I will let you know

Comment: @NoEm Thanks that works perfectly

Comment: you are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@NoEm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5683035/no-em) I managed to get it working but implementing `OnClickListener`'s like this:

```
chk1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        chk1.setChecked(true);
        chk2.setChecked(false);
    }
});
chk2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        chk2.setChecked(true);
        chk1.setChecked(false);
    }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that in matters of design, the checkboxes are for when you want to let the user take multiple options. I think that what you should try to use is the radioputton, here's a link:

[Radiobutton reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioButton/)

Comment: Like I said in my question.. I know it is against design principal, but I'm looking for a work around.

Comment: I would go the Radiobutton route, and skin it like a checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Two variants:
First is Java

```
final CheckBox cb1 = findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    final CheckBox cb2 = findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    cb1.setChecked(true);

    cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
            cb2.setChecked(!isChecked);
        }
    });

    cb2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
            cb1.setChecked(!isChecked);
        }
    });
```

or Kotlin as second

```
val cb1 = this.findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.checkBox1)
    val cb2 = this.findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.checkBox2)

    cb1.isChecked = true

    cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->  cb2.isChecked = !isChecked }
    cb2.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->  cb1.isChecked = !isChecked }
```

Comment: I already got it working, but I was interested if your answer will work as well so I tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: can you link me a full code which didn't work? Since it works fine on my device